# C++ inheritance misunderstanding

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Why don't `std:cout` prints `3`?

With the intention of constructing a derived object with a pre-defined `m_size` the following code was developed. But it seems the idea isn't correctly implemented since `std:cout` print anything but `Data1Size`. Could someone please correct me?

```
untitled.pro    

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    genericdata.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    genericdata.h
```

main.cpp

```
#include "genericdata.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Data1 data;

    return 0;
}
```

genericdata.h

```
#ifndef GENERICDATA_H
#define GENERICDATA_H

#include <iostream>

class GenericData
{
    int m_size;

protected:
    const int Data1Size = 3;

public:
    explicit GenericData(int size);
};

class Data1 : public GenericData {
public:
    Data1() : GenericData(Data1Size) {}
};

#endif // GENERICDATA_H
```

genericdata.cpp

```
#include "genericdata.h"

GenericData::GenericData(int size) :
    m_size(size)
{
    std::cout << "m_size: " << m_size << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what output do you get? What output do you expect?

Comment: Got `m_size: 57` and was expecting `m_size: 3`. Makes sense?

Comment: What happened when you single stepped with a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In-class initializer for non-static member `Data1Size`

```
const int Data1Size = 3;
```

simply means that the compiler will generate an implicit constructor initializer list entry for `Data1Size` in the constructor of `GenericData`. So, in reality the constructor of `GenericData` will look as follows

```
GenericData::GenericData(int size) :
    m_size(size), Data1Size(3)
{
    std::cout << "m_size: " << m_size << std::endl;
}
```

It is the constructor of `GenericData` that sets `Data1Size` to its initial value of `3`.

However, you are accessing `Data1Size` in the *derived* class *before* the constructor of base class `GenericData` had a chance to do anything. At that moment `Data1Size` is still uninitialized.

Comment: I think I understand the issue now. Instead, make `const static int Data1Size = 3;` is the correct approach?

Comment: @KcFnMi: Yes, if you want this value to always be `3` for all instances of these classes, then the proper thing to do would be `static const int Data1Size = 3;`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Data1Size before it is set here:

```
Data1() : GenericData(Data1Size) {}
```

This accesses `Data1Size` before the `GenericData` has been constructed. After all, you're preparing the arguments to call the constructor, so it can't have been constructed yet. But `Data1Size` is a member of `GenericData` -- you have to already have an instance of that class to access it.